# Constant member in struct returning 0 even after initialization

Tags: c++

I'm creating a `struct` to hold data about a texture that I need for my project. This structure has five members:
The texture atlas width (The amount of textures in one row),
The texture atlas height (The amount of textures in one column),
The texture unit width (The inverse of atlas width),
The texture unit height (The inverse of atlas height)
and an unsigned `GLint` storing the textures id.

However, even after initializing these members in the constructor, I receive an `ArithmeticException` later in the program due to the atlas width and height both being set to 0.

I've tried rearranging my code and trying other seemingly random changes but none have worked.

The way my project (or at least the relevant part) is set up is that I have a header and source file for my `TextureData` struct. I create a constant object of this type in a header named "GeneralData.h". I don't have a source file associated with this header so all of the implementations are contained in there as well.

This is the TextureData code:

```
// TextureData.h
struct TextureData
{
    const int ATLAS_WIDTH;
    const int ATLAS_HEIGHT;
    const float TEXTURE_UNIT_WIDTH;
    const float TEXTURE_UNIT_HEIGHT;

    GLuint TEXTURE_ID;

    TextureData(int, int);

    virtual ~TextureData() {}
};

// TextureData.cpp
#ifndef STB_IMAGE_IMPLEMENTATION
#define STB_IMAGE_IMPLEMENTATION
#include <../stb_image.h>
#endif // STB_IMAGE_IMPLEMENTATION

TextureData::TextureData(int atlas_width, int atlas_height):
    ATLAS_WIDTH(atlas_width),
    ATLAS_HEIGHT(atlas_height),
    TEXTURE_UNIT_WIDTH(1.0f / ATLAS_WIDTH),
    TEXTURE_UNIT_HEIGHT(1.0f / ATLAS_HEIGHT)
{
    glGenTextures(1, &TEXTURE_ID);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, TEXTURE_ID);

    int width;
    int height;

    unsigned char* pixels = stbi_load("res/block_textures.png", &width, &height, nullptr, 4);

    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, width, height, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, pixels);

    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
}
```

This is the relevant part of the GeneralData header:

```
const TextureData BLOCK_TEXTURE(8, 8);

// These functions are called at some point with index = 0.
// Their behaviour should not be undefined
inline float tex_coord_x(int index)
{
    return index % BLOCK_TEXTURE.ATLAS_WIDTH * BLOCK_TEXTURE.TEXTURE_UNIT_WIDTH;
}

inline float tex_coord_y(int index)
{
    return index / BLOCK_TEXTURE.ATLAS_HEIGHT * BLOCK_TEXTURE.TEXTURE_UNIT_HEIGHT;
}
```

As stated above I get a runtime exception (arithmetic) because I am dividing by zero. I should be dividing by (or modulus) eight in this case (and by 0.125f in the case of TEXTURE_UNIT_WIDTH).

This is where the functions are called. This is under the function definitions and the BLOCK_TEXTURE definition.

// EDIT:

```
template <typename T, size_t SIZE, typename FUNCTION>
inline std::array<T, SIZE> make_array (FUNCTION func)
{
    std::array<T, SIZE> arr;
    unsigned int index = 0;
    std::for_each(arr.begin(), arr.end(), [&func, &index, &arr](const T& val){ arr[index] = func(index); index++; });

    return arr;
}

const std::array<float, B_LAST * 6> TEXTURE_COORDS = make_array<float, B_LAST * 6>([](unsigned int index){ return index%2 == 0? tex_coord_x(TEXTURE_INDICES[index / 2]) : tex_coord_y(TEXTURE_INDICES[index / 2 + 1]); });
```

Comment: It might be a case of https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/ctors#static-init-order

Comment: I just looked at your link but that doesn't really seem to apply here since both functions and the object are defined in the same file.

Comment: Are you sure your functions are not called in constructor or destructor of another global/static object?

Comment: remove inline maybe?

Comment: I cant do that. Multiple definition error.

Comment: There's a very simple check to be made. Is `TextureData::TextureData` ever called? Fire up a debugger, set a breakpoint, run. Do you get a hit?

Comment: I call the function in a custom make_array function where I use std::for_each to create an array and fill it according to a lambda. But it is not called in constructor. (And in case anyone Is wondering that function is defined after the BLOCK_TEXTURE aswell

Comment: sounds like a hint ...

Comment: I just tested with the debugger. The values are initialized just fine. I don't know why the value is suddenly reading 0 though.

Comment: @Anders What do you mean?

Comment: @J.Lengel put a breakpoint in the initialization, then when the breakpoint is hit, put a data breakpoint on the fields after they are initialized, and see if that breakpoint ever gets hit indicating they are being overwritten.

Comment: They're constant so that shouldn't be possible

Comment: Also, how do I setup a data breakpoint? I'm using the CodeBlocks IDE and I only see regular breakpoints

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you have static init fiasco in your code (but I'm not 100% sure, this is some very strange part of C++ and it's UBs)

You define a global variable in a header file. You mentioned in comments that you cannot remove `inline` keyword, because you will get multiple definition errors, and that's true. **But you also have multiple definitions of your global variables in every translation unit.**

Every file including `GeneralData.h` has it's own definition of `BLOCK_TEXTURE`, so it is possible that one file will access variable from the other file. And it may be not initialized yet.

You can "confirm" (as much as you can confirm UB) static init fiasco by checking whether exception occurs before `main` starts or after that. Use debugger and check backtrace when it occurs or simply print something in the very first line of `main`.

The solution would be pretty simple: You should define your global variables only in one file.

In `GeneralData.h`:

```
extern const TextureData BLOCK_TEXTURE;
extern const std::array<float, B_LAST * 6> TEXTURE_COORDS ;
```

In `GeneralData.cpp`:

```
const TextureData BLOCK_TEXTURE(8, 8);
const std::array<float, B_LAST * 6> TEXTURE_COORDS = make_array<float, B_LAST * 6>([](unsigned int index){ return index%2 == 0? tex_coord_x(TEXTURE_INDICES[index / 2]) : tex_coord_y(TEXTURE_INDICES[index / 2 + 1]); });
```

Comment: Ironically enough as soon as I changed the variables to extern I got a multiple definition error

Comment: @J.Lengel Did you put definitions in a cpp file? You shouldn't get multiple definitions if you only have one definition in one file...

Comment: I put the definition in a .cpp file and it fixed the problem. The source linking probably helped me in this case. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Hmm.

This code works fine after cleaning and putting it in single file. Main hint to your problem is your own statement "This is the relevant part of the GeneralData header". You put your const value into header and included it multiple times. Const values have internal linkage by default (why? no idea...), which means you get multiple versions of your BLOCK_TEXTURE variable. And your code probably uses wrong one, while your debugger caught different one. Compare pointers to this in constructor of BLOCK_TEXTURE and at the moment your exception is raised to be sure. As a solution add extern keyword to turn definition of BLOCK_TEXTURE into declaration:

```
extern const TextureData BLOCK_TEXTURE;
```

and define it somewhere in single file:

```
const TextureData BLOCK_TEXTURE(8, 8);
```

Note, that this will probably introduce static initialization fiasco to you at some point. Therefore i suggest using static function instead (in header):

```
static inline GET_BLOCK_TEXTURE() {
    static const TextureData BLOCK_TEXTURE(8, 8);
    return BLOCK_TEXTURE;
}
```

This will make sure, that BLOCK_TEXTURE is initialized at first time you will use it.

Comment: Wouldn't this create a bunch of copies of BLOCK_TEXTURE though?

Comment: Otherwise this is pretty much the same as @Yksisarvinen's answer so thank you to both of you

Comment: No. Compilator is required to merge all inline functions from binary into one. So you will get only one copy. Unless you use your header in more, than one binary (for example two dll's).

Comment: Our answers are similar. Using function is preferred solution, as it protects you from static initialization fiasco. And since you rely on global initialization, you will hit this sooner or later.

Comment: Good to know. Thank you. I will definitely consider that when coding in the future.